# iam not able to install java and android studio

Tags: java, dpkg

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gconf-service_3.2.6-3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconf/gconfd-2', which is also in package gconf-service-backend 3.2.6-0ubuntu2
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gconf-service_3.2.6-3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Java:

- 1. Open Terminal.
- 2. Type in `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-jre`

For Android Studio:

- 1. Open Terminal.
- 2. Type `sudo add-apt-repository ppa: paolorotolo / android-studio`
- 3. Type `sudo apt-get update`
- 4. Type `sudo apt-get install android-studio`
- 5. Open the repository you installed it in and right click, then select "Run in Terminal".

You may need to connect the jdk to Android Studio, depending on which version, and if you get an error then try installing OracleJDK instead.

Comment: this below thing i got at java 2nd step

Comment: You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gconf2 : Depends: gconf-service (= 3.2.6-3)
 openjdk-7-jre : Depends: openjdk-7-jre-headless (= 7u91-2.6.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)

Comment: Depends: libgif4 (>= 4.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libatk-wrapper-java-jni (>= 0.30.4-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                 Recommends: libgnome2-0 but it is not going to be installed
                 Recommends: libgnomevfs2-0 but it is not going to be installed
                 Recommends: libgconf2-4 but it is not going to be installed
                 Recommends: fonts-dejavu-extra but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).